# ListView with specialized buttons inside adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

This is the custom class

```
public class TextWithButton{
protected String playerName;

public TextWithButton(String playerName){
    this.playerName=playerName;
}
```

And this is the custom adapter

```
public class TextWithButtonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TextWithButton>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<TextWithButton> data = null;
boolean isAddable;

public TextWithButtonAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<TextWithButton> data, boolean isAddable) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.isAddable = isAddable;
}

@Override
public void add(TextWithButton object)
{
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    TextWithButtonHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new TextWithButtonHolder();
        holder.playerNameText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
        holder.processPlayerFab = (FloatingActionButton)row.findViewById(R.id.process_player);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (TextWithButtonHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    TextWithButton textWithButton = data.get(position);
    holder.playerNameText.setText(textWithButton.playerName);
    if(isAddable)
    {
        holder.processPlayerFab.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
        holder.processPlayerFab.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.processPlayerFab.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
        holder.processPlayerFab.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
    }

    return row;
}

static class TextWithButtonHolder
{
    TextView playerNameText;
    FloatingActionButton processPlayerFab;
}
```

I'm trying to set an OnClickListener for that FloatingActionButton from outside the adapter, as there are multiple functionalities I want to implement for it. For instance, I want to have two adapters in some class, in which they call two different functions upon clicking them. I would also like to avoid ListView's setOnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand that you largely want to access the floatingactionbutton from its container view to set an onclicklistner specifically on it.

A way to do this would be a kind of a for loop going through say some numerical tags you put in the floatingactionbutton.  Such as

```
floatingbutton.setTag("tag" + position);
```

and then accessing the button somewhere potentially in a for loop going throughout the listview adding specific onclick effects in its container class.

```
(FloatingActionButton) listview.findViewWithTag("tag" + (int));
```

this would allow you to add onclicklisteners to the floating action button from its container class.

Unless of course I misunderstood the question.